# Create function that can loop for numerous inputs

Tags: matlab

I created a MATLAB function that runs bootstrap regression based on your data and the sample size desired. The only inputs required are the Y data, X data and 'n' the bootstrap sample size required, e.g. boot(Y,X,10).

How can I create an input that will loop for numerous sample sizes? I.e. something like boot(Y,X,[10,30,100]).

This is important as bootstrap can take quite a while to run, so it is ideal if you can just enter the desired sample sizes and leave the computer while running instead of entering the same command three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily as follows:

```
bootstrapSampleSize = [10 30 100];
for i=1:length(bootstrapSampleSize)
    yourResult{i}=boot(Y,X,bootstrapSampleSize(i)); %stores the results in a cell array
end
```

This can be made completely interactive with the use of `input` command but I will leave that upto you.

Comment: Let me just clarify what you have entered. This loops the function 3 times for each sample size? In my function m file, I would just enter these lines? I am just sceptical as to why you are looping.

Comment: This will loop once for 10, then once or 30 and once for 100. So in your m-file if you enter these lines, after execution you will find the result in `yourResult{1}`, `yourResult{2}` and `yourResult{3}`